# DateTimeFormatter: include optional field based on the value of another field

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time, localtime

I want to format a `java.time.LocalTime`, but the format can vary according to its value:

- if **hour of day** is 12 or 0, use the format `HH:mm`
- else, use the format `HH:mm:ss`

Of course I could do it like this:

```
if (t.getHour() == 12 || t.getHour() == 0) {
    // use "HH:mm" formatter
} else {
    // use "HH:mm:ss" formatter
}
```

But for that I need to create 2 different formatters.

I want to use just **one** formatter that can be reused many times:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = // create this "conditional" formatter
fmt.format(LocalTime.of(14, 0))); // 14:00:00
fmt.format(LocalTime.of(12, 0))); // 12:00
```

I'm trying to do it with a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("HH:mm")
    // how to append seconds (and the ":" before it) only if hour of day is not (12 or 0)?
    .appendLiteral(":").appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .toFormatter();
```

I tried with `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.optionalStart()` and `optionalEnd()` methods, and also with `appendOptional()`, but these methods only check if the field being appended is present.
They don't have an optional behaviour based on another field's value.

How can I do it with just one formatter (if possible)?

Comment: There is no way to do this with a single formatter that you can create independently of the `LocalTime` object to be formatted - `DateTimeFormatter` simply does not have such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and the method [appendText(TemporalField,Map)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendText-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-java.util.Map-). It allows you to convert each number to a specific piece of text. However, since you want to base the seconds on the hour, you'll have to setup a map of 86400 entries, one for every second in the day. But it will then work as a single formatter.

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0L, "00:00");
map.put(1L, "00:00");  // would normally be 00:00:01
map.put(2L, "00:00");  // would normally be 00:00:02
map.put(60L, "00:01");
// and so on
map.put(3600L, "01:00:00");
map.put(3601L, "01:00:01");
// and so on to 86399
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendText(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, map)
  .toFormatter();
```

A map of 86400 entries is of course silly, but its the best you can do with the API as is. Really, there needs to be an `appendText(TemporalField, LongFunction<String>)` method added to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` (which would result in a formatter that could not be used for parsing).

Comment: You don't have to use a `HashMap` containing 86400 entries! The `Map` is just an interface. You can implement it with a class whose `get()` calculates the format string based on the input number of seconds.

Comment: The map is copied within the JDK, so while you can write an implementation of `Map`, it will be looped over every time to extract all the values, which would be woefuly inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you'd want to do it like this, but you were almost there:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtfb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("HH:mm");
if (t.getHour() % 12 != 0) {
    dtfb.appendLiteral(":").appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2);
}
DateTimeFormatter fmt = dtfb.toFormatter();
```

Comment: Ah, the formatter has to be independent of the LocalTime it needs to format .... that is a significant change

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.optionalStart()` just as you've tried, but you will also have to create a wrapper class that wraps a `LocalTime` in which `isSupported(SECONDS_OF_MINUTE)` returns `false` if the hour is 0 or 12.

In my opinion this is too much hassle and doesn't really increase clarity (not by much anyway) or performance. Using two separate formatters is easier.

Comment: My original intention was to use just one formatter because I could have more specific cases (and the number of formatters could increase with it). But probably there's no easy way and I'll just have to use lots of formatters...

Answer (score 1):

I could do it by following the suggestion made by @Klitos [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001290/7605325) (create a wrapper).
But overriding `isSupported` (as he suggested) **didn't work**.

Actually I had to override `getLong` method and throw an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` when the field is not supposed to be formatted. Short version of my solution:

```
public class LocalTimeWrapper
    implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, Comparable<LocalTimeWrapper>, Serializable {

    private LocalTime time;

    public static LocalTimeWrapper of(int hour, int minute) {
        return new LocalTimeWrapper(LocalTime.of(hour, minute));
    }

    private LocalTimeWrapper(LocalTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    // implement Temporal and TemporalAdjuster
    // (interface methods like isSupported() and until() delegate to "time" field)

    @Override
    public long getLong(TemporalField field) {
        if (field == ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE) {
            if (this.time.getHour() % 12 == 0) {
                // don't format seconds when hour is 12 or 0
                throw new UnsupportedTemporalTypeException("some message");
            }
        }

        return this.time.getLong(field);
    }
}
```

With this code, it worked:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("HH:mm")
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(":")
    .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();

f.format(LocalTimeWrapper.of(14, 0));  // 14:00:00
f.format(LocalTimeWrapper.of(12, 0));  // 12:00
f.format(LocalTimeWrapper.of(0, 15));  // 00:15
f.format(LocalTimeWrapper.of(15, 30)); // 15:30:00
```

But as many of you have told me, that seems to be too much work and it's probably better to use lots of different formatters (or [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44004217/7605325)) - *and I must admit that I tried to finish this code just to know if it's possible*.

I've used **jdk1.8.0_111** for this test.

Answer (score 1):

**First to say, I am really not sure if a simple workaround using just two formatters is not more adequate for your problem.**

Every way to use only ONE formatter will inevitably cause some extra performance penalty compared with the simple approach (pseudo code):

```
if (time.getHour() == 0 || time.getHour() == 12) {
  formatterHHMM.format(time);
} else {
  formatterHHMMSS.format(time);
}
```

It is just one formatter extra. **Keep in mind that it is a good idea to store the two immutable formatters as static constants.** Otherwise, if you insist on defining ONE formatter, then read further:

---

As S. Colebourne and Jesper have indicated, there is no special way inside the context of JSR-310 to do what you wish. However, my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) would 
enable this by following code. I have even given two slightly different ways because your question was not quite clear to me about how to handle the subhour-precision.

The first way always prints "HH:mm" if the hour is 0 or 12 without taking into account possible minute- or second-parts.

```
    ChronoFormatter<LocalTime> f1 =
        ChronoFormatter.setUp(PlainTime.axis(TemporalType.LOCAL_TIME), Locale.ROOT)
            .startOptionalSection((t) -> t.getInt(PlainTime.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM) == 12)
            .addCustomized(
                PlainTime.COMPONENT,
                ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("HH:mm", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT)
            )
            .endSection()
            .startOptionalSection((t) -> t.getInt(PlainTime.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM) != 12)
            .addCustomized(
                PlainTime.COMPONENT,
                ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("HH:mm:ss", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT)
            )
            .endSection()
        .build();
    System.out.println(f1.format(LocalTime.now())); // 16:35:29
    System.out.println(f1.format(LocalTime.of(12, 15))); // 12:15
    System.out.println(f1.format(LocalTime.of(12, 0))); // 12:00
```

The second way only prints "HH:mm" if the time is equal to exact noon or midnight. Of course, the [print condition](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.Builder.html#startOptionalSection-net.time4j.engine.ChronoCondition-) could also be specified as something like `t.equals(PlainTime.of(0)) || t.equals(PlainTime.of(12))`.

```
    ChronoFormatter<LocalTime> f2 =
        ChronoFormatter.setUp(PlainTime.axis(TemporalType.LOCAL_TIME), Locale.ROOT)
            .startOptionalSection(
                (t) -> t.getInt(PlainTime.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM) == 12
                    && t.get(PlainTime.PRECISION) == ClockUnit.HOURS)
            .addCustomized(
                PlainTime.COMPONENT,
                ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("HH:mm", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT)
            )
            .endSection()
            .startOptionalSection(
                (t) -> t.getInt(PlainTime.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM) != 12
                    || t.get(PlainTime.PRECISION) != ClockUnit.HOURS)
            .addCustomized(
                PlainTime.COMPONENT,
                ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("HH:mm:ss", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT)
            )
            .endSection()
            .build();
    System.out.println(f2.format(LocalTime.now())); // 16:35:29
    System.out.println(f2.format(LocalTime.of(12, 15))); // 12:15:00
    System.out.println(f2.format(LocalTime.of(12, 0))); // 12:00
```

This solution does not require a map with 86400 entries or more.

In contrast to the suggested idea behind `appendText(TemporalField, LongFunction<String>)`, this kind of formatter would also enable parsing (although here the single pattern "HH:mm[:ss]" would be sufficient). That is also the reason why I have rejected this idea as enhancement to Time4J (I don't want to prevent parsing).

The independent format engine of Time4J was developed to fill gaps in Java-8. By the way, I recommend to store the formatter of Time4J also as static constant (it is immutable).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I accepted Stephen's solution because: 1- It was decided to not add another dependency just for this case; 2- It won't be used for parsing; 3- No need to create extra wrapper classes, as I did [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44004119/7605325); I know the 86400-entry map is not ideal, but I can live with it (or maybe I'll give up this idea and use lots of formatters, who knows). And there are other use cases that will require smaller maps and we think it's ok to manage. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SimpleDateFormatter("HH:mm" + (((t.getHour() % 12) == 0) ? "" : ":ss");
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need (as it'll create lots of formatters); I've updated the question